# Lat/Long query won't work when the lat and long is inner joined. Why?

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

This query works perfectly fine for me to inner join a table of locations with the lat and long meta values from a data table.

```
SELECT
locations_table.location_id AS locationid, lat_table.meta_value AS lat, 
long_table.meta_value AS lng

FROM locations_db.locations AS locations_table         
INNER JOIN  data.data_meta AS lat_table  ON 
lat_table.location_id=locations_table.locaiton_id      
INNER JOIN  data.data_meta AS long_table ON 
long_table.location_id=locations_table.locaiton_id      

WHERE locations_table.master_location='$mastergroupid'
AND lat_table.meta_key='latitude' AND long_table.meta_key='longitude'
```

But when I add in this formula for calculating distance from a latitude and longitude, it throws a boolean error.

```
SELECT locations_table.location_id AS locationid, lat_table.meta_value AS 
lat, long_table.meta_value AS lng,
 SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (lat - $lat), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ($lng - lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
```

I know that "as distance" formula works in tables where the lat and long is just part of the table and not inner joined.

What am I missing? Can I not do that AS DISTANCE calculation on an inner joined value, because it's not technically in the table yet?

Comment: UPDATE - it is saying that the lat and long are unknown in the AS DISTANCE subquery. how is that possible? they're defined

Comment: I guess it's hard to help without seeing the actual query but if I understand correctly then yes, the subquery  alias isn't available to the 'super' query. Instead, you can write out the distance part longhand. This may seem tedious, but it's not particularly inefficient.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not unusual to construct a udf or sproc for calculating distances. It saves a bit of typing.

Comment: Why do you have these dollar signs in your formula (`$lat` and `$lng`)?

Comment: @Pharaoh - that would be PHP or Perl syntax for variables in the client language; they would show up as constants in the SQL.

Comment: Having lat/lng off in other tables is not a very scalable way to build the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given column aliases to the `meta_value` columns and are using these aliases inside the `select` clause. This is not possible, see

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html:

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column:

You have to write the full qualified table+column-name in the calculation:

```
SELECT 
  locations_table.location_id AS locationid, 
  lat_table.meta_value AS lat, 
  long_table.meta_value AS lng,
  SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat_table.meta_value - $lat), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ($lng - long_table.meta_value) * COS(lat_table.meta_value / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
  [... rest of query ...]
```

Comment: If it's correct you are free to accept the answer as correct :-)